# Как разделить сумму каждого столбца на все значения в данном столбце в pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Есть сводная таблица. На скрине пример. Я хочу поделить каждое значение строки на сумму каждого столбца, чтобы вывести долю каждой строки в зависимости от суммы столбца. Как я могу это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. вопрос должен включать воспроизводимый пример данных. 2. заголовок вашего вопроса противоречит тому, что написано внутри вопроса. Вы уж определитесь, что на что вам нужно поделить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а что мешает применить метод `apply` к датафрейму?

Например, при датафрейме

```
C           bar       foo
A                        
one   -0.493473  0.213471
three -0.910192  0.581473
two    0.588947  0.009149
```

применение

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x/x.sum())
```

даст

```
C           bar       foo
A                        
one    0.605698  0.265480
three  1.117186  0.723142
two   -0.722884  0.011378
```

Comment: Боже, действительно...

Answer (score 2):

Один из нескольких вариантов векторизированного решения:

```
df /= df.sum()
```